# Issues with initializing new object

Tags: c#, object, constructor

When I try to construct the following object:

```
Tijdschrift tijdschrift = new Tijdschrift 
{ 
    Id = "ID01", 
    Titel = "Scientific American", 
    Datum = new DateTime(2014, 8, 1), 
    Uitgeverij = "Scientific American" 
};
```

I get the following error:

> Error CS7036  There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Id' of 'Tijdschrift.Tijdschrift(string, string, DateTime, string)'    Catalogus   C:\Users\Robiin\Documents\Labo03\Labo03\Program.cs  13

I have no idea why honestly, my constructor is written as below.

```
public Tijdschrift(string Id, string titel, DateTime datum, string uitgeverij)
{
    Datum = datum;
    this.Id = Id;
    Titel = titel;
    Uitgeverij = uitgeverij;
}
```

Comment: you are confused with constructor parameters and property initializer

Comment: You are using object initialization syntax using a constructor with no parameters (in other words, you are not calling that constructor). Instead,  `new Tijdschrift("ID01", ...`

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of the class  `Tijdschrift` (I mean the declaration of the properties involved)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using [object initializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx) syntax. The code you posted first tries to call parameterless constructor, then sets properties. Use parenthesis `()` to pass constructor parameters:

```
Tijdschrift tijdschrift = new Tijdschrift ("ID01", 
    "Scientific American", 
    new DateTime(2014, 8, 1), 
    "Scientific American");
```

Comment: Alright, that seems to do it, I didn't realise this. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution to your problem would be to add a parameterless constructor. Then your object initializer works fine.

```
public class Tijdschrift {
    public DateTime Datum {get;set;}
    public string Id {get;set;}
    public string Titel {get;set;}
    public string Uitgeverij {get;set;}

    public Tijdschrift(){}

    public Tijdschrift(string Id, string titel, DateTime datum, string uitgeverij)
    {
        Datum = datum;
        this.Id = Id;
        Titel = titel;
        Uitgeverij = uitgeverij;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the constructor like this instead:

```
Tijdschrift tijdschrift = new Tijdschrift ("ID01",
                                           "Scientific American",
                                            new DateTime(2014, 8, 1),
                                            "Scientific American");
```